# There is a possible use Symfony DI like in Laravel?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

When I need to use the capabilities the DI Symfony I have to adjust a file services.yml. But Laravel can find all dependencies without settings. There is possible to do this in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose can be used a DunglasActionBundle.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Symfony DI now as of 2.8, and it is known as auto-wiring.

You can read more [about it here.](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-service-auto-wiring)

Comment: In Symfony I should setup services.yml for each service, and this is very ugly. But a DunglasActionBundle registers all my services automatically!

Comment: It isn't ugly, if you're questioning configuration of services then maybe you don't need a service container.